# Install Foxit Reader on Ubuntu 16.04: Installation does not start

Tags: 16.04, foxitreader

I tried to install Foxit Reader on Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit. I followed [these instructions](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-foxit-pdf-reader-ubuntu-16-04). However, the installation does not start and the progression is blocked at 0%.

[image: see the progression]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please close that window and run `sudo apt install -f` and try again

Comment: Thanks George. I cannot close it. It is blocked. Can I run that code without closing the windows?

Comment: open a another terminal and run `sudo pgrep foxit` lets get the pid of that process

Comment: It is blocked again

Comment: It's best you report this to the app owners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, but it fixed now by providing `sudo` before  `./Foxit...`, may be you can try to add `sudo` in front of command installation. I tried this :

`sudo ./FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609\(r08f07f8\).x64.run`

Comment: Thak you so much. It works now